# <R> Error in cph(Surv(OStime, OSstatus) ~ 1, data = OSNUx) : object 'n' not found, How to solve?

Tags: r

I want to do cox forward stepwise regression. However,

```
 Error in cph(Surv(OStime, OSstatus) ~ 1, data = OSNUx) :    
   object 'n' not found
```

How can I solve this problem? I remember the code used to run normally in previous versions of R, but an error occurred in R 4.3

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Overall Survial (OS) Forward Stepwise Regression

# 1.Build regression

null <- cph(Surv(OStime,OSstatus) ~ 1, data = OSNUx) # Establish an empty linear regression (intercept only)
full <- cph(Surv(OStime,OSstatus) ~ ., data = OSNUx) # Establish the upper bound, which is the full linear regression

# 2. Use step(), adding variables one by one
forward.cph = step(null, 
                  # Start from the empty model, adding variables one by one,
                  # Will not exceed the full linear regression
                  scope=list(lower=null, upper=full), 
                  direction="forward")
summary(forward.cph)
```

I google the error msg but no proper answer for the error.
How to write the stepwise regession code without error?